# Start a new Java project inside an existing Git repository in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm a new Eclipse user and I'm using Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, which should include a Git plugin.

I initialized a Git repository and created inside it a folder structure like:

- folder1/
- folder2/
- folder3/
- code/

Now I would like to create a new Java project inside the *code* folder, and see the whole repository under the Package Explore tab, and control it using the menu.

How can I do that?

Comment: It has nothing to do with GIt, its pure eclipse question.

Comment: IntelliJ Community edition is far better for git integration, and is a far better IDE. Maybe give it a try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see your repository contents in project explorer, you can select your repository in the git repositories view and choose import projects... import as a general project and choose the top level directory...
To create a java project inside your repository, you will first need to create the java project and then right click your project, choose team->share and select the location in your git repo. Hope this helps.